Do you need to show the I-797 when entering the US from Canada by car on an H-1B
Do you need to show the I-797 when entering the US from Canada by car on an H-1B when you have the passport with a valid visa stamp. We are considering driving from Glacier NP to Banff for a few days.

Yes, if you're asked for it you need to be able to show it. Whether to ask for it is up to the officer, from my (admittedly stale) experience they do ask.
